# Rabbitmq understanding channel, consumer and connection statistics

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

My problem referres  to the statistics that are displayed in the management plugin. When not used rabbitmq stats looks like that:

[image]

I am using rabbitmq to create a REQ/REP socket. For each connected client a new queue is created. So we have 4 queues now:

[image]

However I don't understand the other numbers.

1. Why are there 8 exchanges initially? (after fresh install)
2. Why are there 2 queues initially? (after fresh install)
3. Why did the other numbers jump from 0 to 4 while I have just 2 clients?

Is this because of the REQ/REP?

Update: I have two application communicating with each other. On the one side I have

```
var context = require('rabbit.js').createContext('amqp://localhost');
var rep = context.socket('REP', {
    prefetch: 1,
    persistent: false
});
rep.connect(someIdentifier);
rep.setEncoding('utf8');

rep.on('data', function(data) {
    //got a request
});
```

And on the other:

```
var context = require('rabbit.js').createContext('amqp://localhost');
var req = context.socket('REQ');
req.setEncoding('utf8');
req.connect(sameIdAsAbove);
req.on('data', function(data) {
    //got a response
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 default exchanges are one of each exchange type + their aliases exchanges (see [Exchanges and Exchange Types section in AMQP 0-9-1 Model Explained](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchanges).

The next 2 exchanges are `amq.rabbitmq.trace` (`topic` type), the one from [Firehose Tracer](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) and `amqp.rabbitmq.log` (also `topic` type) from where you can consume log entries during debugging (just bind by `#` key for example).

These exchanges created in every vhost, by the way. The `amq` prefix comes from AMQP conventions to name AMQP related entities with `amq` prefix. The `rabbitmq` part stands for RabbitMQ-specific features.

So it all about conventions.

As to 2 default queues, it really depends of your installation type, while default config may vary. Vanilla RabbitMQ installation gives you no queues.

If you have 4 active consumers (process that waiting for a new message to appear in queue) that stay connected they will utilize at least one connection each and one channel per connection.

Why your queues number changes is hard to say without seen actual code.

**Update:**

4 connections and 4 channels (to communicate with AMQP broker you need to open at least one channel, it's described in [4.3 Connection Multiplexing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) section in AMQP protocol) comes that underlying implementation creates duplex stream (one for each application instance) that probably use two connections to makes read and write events happen independently.

P.S.: actually, fresh install may import pre-defined config and configure many other options from access policy, vhosts, users, exchanges, queues, bindings to HA, clustering and many other.

Comment: +1 Thank you!! I updated my question with some code. Maybe you can explain why I have 4 connections?

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation about channels and connections. As to queue - post initial queues name in comments, I guess they are created by your app or installer.